# App getting crash when click on GoogleSignIn button. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am using Google Sign-In SDK 4.0.1. When I press googleSignInButton then app will be crash. And gave below error, how to fix this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes: com.googleusercontent.apps.107731993306-6s44u18onibp6gi0ddj94si1aifshhg6'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ac0d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010110121e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b2a2b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   xxxxx                           0x000000010084b3cb -[GIDSignIn signInWithOptions:] + 246
    4   xxxxx                           0x000000010084efc2 -[GIDSignInButton pressed] + 242
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001028f78bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000102a7dc38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000102a7df51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000102a7ce4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000102965545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000102966c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001029139ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010310072d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001030f9463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a65761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a4a98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a49e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a49884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001074cfa6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001028f5c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  xxxxxxxx                           0x00000001007c449f main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000104d5368d start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`
```

My AppDelegate.Swift is

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
   if (error == nil) {

    let userId:NSString = user.userID as NSString;                  // For client-side use only!
    let idToken: NSString = user.authentication.idToken as NSString; // Safe to send to the server
    let fullName:NSString = user.profile.name as NSString;
    let givenName:NSString = user.profile.givenName as NSString;
    let familyName:NSString = user.profile.familyName as NSString;
    let email:NSString = user.profile.email as NSString;
    print(userId)
    print(userId,idToken,fullName,givenName,familyName,email)
    }

   else {
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let kclientID:NSString = "107731993306-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"

   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kclientID as String!

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject], annotation:Any, sourceApplication:String?) -> Bool {

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication:sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

> Please give me the solution. Why it is crashed?

Comment: Did you add URLScheme into project ?

Comment: @VikasDhasal did you put delegates method in appdelagates ?

Comment: @VikasDhasal its to complicated to read this comment so updated your question with delegates method implimentation code .

Answer (score 170, accepted):

As the error clearly says, your app is missing support for the url schemes.

Add the following schemes to your info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>***Your bundle ID***</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.107731993306-6s44u18onibp6gi0ddj94si1aifshhg6</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>***Something here***</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Check this url for your id => https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

Your info.plist should look like ->

[image]

Comment: For Bundle Identifier you can use `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` instead of hardcoded string

Comment: Google tells us how to fix this in this link: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#ios-integration

Comment: Thank you, the ui saved me as I had two sections of the CFBundleURLTypes in my info.plist, the xcode reads the first one only

Comment: What is the meant to go in ***Something here***?

Comment: Only the middle key was useful in my case. I also had to add a GIDClientID key outside of CDBundleURLTypes.

Answer (score 148):

You have to add a URL scheme to your project

1. Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in the left tree view. Select your app from the **TARGETS** section, then select the Info tab, and expand the *URL Types section*
2. Click the + button, and add a URL scheme -*com.googleusercontent.apps.107731993306-6s44u18onibp6gi0ddj94si1aifshh*

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating#add_a_url_scheme_for_google_sign-in_to_your_project

[image]

Comment: This is IMO the easier (and typical) way to achieve the same thing as the accepted answer.

Comment: This must be the perfect answer! I just add a field under URL TYPES in info and it works! adding the same to the plist.info not working

Comment: struggled also with this issue, SHA 1 key was already added but app crashed on every click on the "login with google" button of my flutter app

Thanks, this answer here solved it. VS code > right click on iOS Folder > open in xcode > copy reversed_client_id from GoogleService-info.plist file you downloaded from firebase and stored to "iOS/Runner" before and add it as new URL Type (see screenshot)

Answer (score 33):

I got that crash too. But accepted answer did not help me.
I have fixed that crash in other way:

Double check that:

In `AppDelegate` **straight** DNS:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "536164374389-ivga9a9at2g31nfmhpvdyhc98yf6afnr.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

In `Info.plist` **reverse** DNS:

```
<string>com.googleusercontent.apps.536164374389-ivga9a9at2g31nfmhpvdyhc98yf6afnr</string>
```

Answer (score 30):

Xcode gives you a string  - Put it here as in the below image

[image]

Comment: for those completely new to xcode, it would be helpful if you tell us where to find this screen

Answer (score 11):

I ran into similar problem. Try this method if other methods didn't help you.

There is a chance you implemented Google and Facebook login together as they are often implemented together.

The latest Google Dev docs make you implement the URL scheme using Your Project Target > Info > URL Types. While Facebook docs will tell you to implement the url scheme in `info.plist` file. When you implement in .plist file the other URL Schemes will be replaced. So implement all URL Schemes in Project's Target section.

[Your project target will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw7cW.png)

Hope someone finds this helpful

Answer (score 7):

For those who came here from Flutter because of the crash of `google_sign_in` package on iOS devices - I've already covered this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60057204/5502121)

Long story short: try to explicitly set properties `hostedDomain` and `clientId`.

```
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn( 
  scopes: ['email', 'profile'],
  hostedDomain: "", 
  clientId: "",);
```

Comment: This was still crashing until I added clientId: "YOUR-CLIENT-ID"

Answer (score 3):

you have to add reversed client id instead of normal one.

Answer (score 2):

I've also waste over 4hours for similar logs (I'm developing ios app by flutter with VScode)

For me the main problem was GoogleService-Info.plist was not truly in the Runner directory.

I MUST had to add the GoogleService-Info.plist by XCODE, by right clicking Runner and add files button.

For overall, I learn that The flutter debugger(or vscode plugin?) does not give full information about the error.

Please look this for more information
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22536

[Check this image for what the 'Right clicking Runner and than add files'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdtjz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

in GoogleSignIn SDK 5.0

add code

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = self

instead of this code

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

Answer (score 1):

in my case, using react native firebase, i had both the web and ios clientiD set, using only the iosClientId solved it for me
`GoogleSignin.configure({ webClientId: '' });`

Answer (score 1):

Just invert the url to be like this: `com.googleusercontent.apps.app_id`

[url types looks finally like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeITH.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two info.plist files one for debbug and one for production, make sure in both of them you've the same URL Schemes.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody tried all the options above and still get same error. Dont forget to add the Google-services.plist file in project.

Answer (score 0):

I found that GoogleServices-info.plist file is different in XCode and my IDE

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I forgot export GoogleService-info.plist from Firebase to my Xcode project.