# 'Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes: com .googleusercontent.apps.xxx'

Tags: ios, google-signin

I found the question and answer in many times but no one from that help  me :( . Anyone can you please help me?

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>http://com.googleusercontent.apps.241222885422-bquei744e1i8q3h0r82k7fm31fbuej7m</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>sixsquarepc08.GoogleIntegration</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This is my info.plist.

These are some questions that I referred,

- [App getting crash when click on GoogleSignIn button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197729/app-getting-crash-when-click-on-googlesignin-button)
- https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/81
- https://medium.com/codespace69/ios-login-google-crash-your-app-is-missing-support-for-the-following-url-schemes-d0e0ede1c01f

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry to all, That was my mistake...There is an unwanted space I put there while declaring googleClienId in `AppDelegate(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "241222885422-bquei744e1i8q3h0r82k7fm31fbuej7m.apps.googleusercontent.com ")`.The space after 
 ".com" was  my problem.It should be `( GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "241222885422-bquei744e1i8q3h0r82k7fm31fbuej7m.apps.googleusercontent.com")`like this.
Please be sure that you entering the clientId in proper way.

Answer (score 11):

You can add your "URL scheme" in "URL types"

[image]

Comment: Then check your plist file is generating properly or not.

Comment: What do I do when my .plist file is not generated properly? I don't see any `CFBundleURLSchemes` key in the Info.plist file

Answer (score 4):

Google Sign-In requires a custom URL Scheme to be added. CFBundleURLSchemes is missing from your info.plist.

I experienced the same issue with my Flutter app and solved it with these steps:

1. From your project folder, go to ios > Runner > GoogleService-Info.plist, copy the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID starting with .com
2. Right click iOS folder > 'Open in Xcode'.
3. Runner (Top folder in the grey panel) -> Runner (In the white panel below Targets),  Info -> URL Types.
4. Click the + button and paste your reversed client ID as a URL scheme. For example com.googleusercontent.apps.1234567890-abcdefg

[screenshot of the xcode Runner Info section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqPSB.png)

Comment: This worked for me in React Native version 0.70.1

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add the CFBundleURLTypes attributes below into the [my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist file.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
            <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.861823949799-vc35cprkp249096uujjn0vvnmcvjppkn</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

See: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#ios-integration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Just solved it, in the appDelegate you should add the right `url scheme` starting with the address and then the numbers ,and not the other way around.

Try this one,

```
AppDelegate(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "apps.googleusercontent.com.241222885422-bquei744e1i8q3h0r82k7fm31fbuej7m")
```