# Flutter iOS simulator errors disappear, no console output in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

the errors disappear really quickly (as shown in the video) so I cannot read them, and there is no debug output in the iOS simulator.

I am using VSCode and Flutter 1.19.

https://streamable.com/go2e89

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42198735/10835183

Comment: Sure, but the problem is, that the output disappears really quickly so I cannot read the errors, not that the app is crashing.

Comment: Actually, the app is crashing. you probably didn't notice. you can pause your video and read the error. Or run the app with Xcode to get a full log

Comment: I know that the app is crashing, but the problem for me is that there is no debug output in console. And I would like to get the output in console in VSCode in iOS as I do get in Android